# why is the logic not working properly in the code?

Tags: c++

the code compiles fine but is not working properly 
in this code i have used an algorithm to sort a list of numbers in ascending order

```
int main(){

struct intlist
{
 int a;
 int b;
 int c;
 int d;
 int e;
 int f;
 int g;
 int h;
 int i;
 int j;
};

intlist letter;

std::cout<<"decide the value of variable : "<<'\n';    
    std::cout<<" a is ";
    std::cin>>letter.a;
    std::cout<<" b is ";
    std::cin>>letter.b;
    std::cout<<" c is ";
    std::cin>>letter.c;
    std::cout<<" d is ";
    std::cin>>letter.d;
    std::cout<<" e is ";
    std::cin>>letter.e;
    std::cout<<" f is ";
    std::cin>>letter.f;
    std::cout<<" g is ";
    std::cin>>letter.g;
    std::cout<<" h is ";
    std::cin>>letter.h;
    std::cout<<" i is ";
    std::cin>>letter.i;
    std::cout<<" j is ";
    std::cin>>letter.j;

    int a=1,b{0},temp;
    for(a=1; a>=9; ++a)  \\using bubble sort algorithm here 
    {

        for(b=0; a>=(9-b); ++b)
         {
             if (b==1)
            {
                if (letter.a > letter.b)
                {
                    temp=letter.b;
                    letter.b=letter.a;
                    letter.a=temp;
                }
            }
        if (b==2)
        {
            if (letter.b> letter.c)
            {
                temp=letter.c;
                letter.c=letter.b;
                letter.b=temp;
            }
        }
        if (b==3)
        {
            if (letter.c> letter.d)
            {
                temp=letter.d;
                letter.d=letter.c;
                letter.c=temp;
            }
        }
        if (b==4)
        {
            if (letter.d> letter.e)
            {
                temp=letter.e;
                letter.e=letter.d;
                letter.d=temp;
            }
        }
        if (b==5)
        {
            if (letter.e> letter.f)
            {
                temp=letter.f;
                letter.f=letter.e;
                letter.e=temp;
            }
        }
        if (b==6)
        {
            if (letter.f> letter.g)
            {
                temp=letter.g;
                letter.g=letter.f;
                letter.f=temp;
            }
        }
        if (b==7)
        {
            if (letter.g> letter.h)
            {
                temp=letter.h;
                letter.h=letter.g;
                letter.g=temp;
            }
        }
        if (b==8)
        {
            if (letter.h> letter.i)
            {
                temp=letter.i;
                letter.i=letter.h;
                letter.h=temp;
            }
        }
        if (b==9)
        {
            if (letter.i> letter.j)
            {
                temp=letter.j;
                letter.j=letter.i;
                letter.i=temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
    std::cout<<"variables now are as follows : "<<'\n';
    std::cout<<" a is "<<letter.a<<'\n';
    std::cout<<" b is "<<letter.b<<'\n';
    std::cout<<" c is "<<letter.c<<'\n';
    std::cout<<" d is "<<letter.d<<'\n';
    std::cout<<" e is "<<letter.e<<'\n';
    std::cout<<" f is "<<letter.f<<'\n';
    std::cout<<" g is "<<letter.g<<'\n';
    std::cout<<" h is "<<letter.h<<'\n';
    std::cout<<" i is "<<letter.i<<'\n';
    std::cout<<" j is "<<letter.j<<'\n';

    return 0;
}
```

the algorithm i have used here is bubble sort .
the code seems to print the value just the same without changing them .

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of [debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging).

Comment: I would suggest [this](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) link over @Scheff 's but the sentiment is the same.  Debugging is an absolutely essential part of software, and you need to learn how to do it.

Comment: `for(a=1; a>=9; ++a)`    means the `for` loop body will never be executed.  This is because, when `a=1`, the test `a >= 9` is false.   Same go for the nested `for` loops.

Answer (score 0):

Question, do you really need to use a struct?

A C type array or a C++ vector would work much better, since this seems unnecessary.

Edit:
I am adding an array example just in case.

```
// Creating the array
int intlist[10];
// Inserting elements into the array
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    std::cout << "Enter element " << i << ": " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> intlist[i];
}
// And so on...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(a=1; a>=9; ++a)
```

this `for` loop sets `a` to `1` and checks if it is `>=9`, which is `false`, so it never enters the loop.

```
for(a=1; a<=9; ++a)
```

should be the correct one.

The `for` loop with `b` has the same problem.

Comments are marked with `//`, not with `\\`.

The inner loop runs once too few, so change it to `for(b=0; a<=(10-b); ++b)`.

https://ideone.com/4MWZKC